# Accessing streamsets web UI on another node in a cluster than where installed, which file system does it 'look in'?

Tags: streamsets

I have a cluster of machines hosting `hadoop (MapR)` and have install streamsets on one of the nodes (say node002) following the RPM [documentation](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#Installation/FullInstall_ServiceStart.html#task_th5_1yj_dx). However, I am accessing the web UI for the `data collector` from another node, node001.

My question is, when I specify files paths (eg. an origin directory), which file system is the web UI going to be referring to? Eg. if I put an origin directory as `/home/myuser/mydata`, will the pipeline created in the web UI be looking for that directory in node001 or node002? New to using streamsets, so a more detailed answer would be appreciated. Thanks.

** Ultimately I am asking this because I am currently getting `"FileNotFound"` and `"permission denied"` errors while trying to follow the documentation's [tutorial](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#Tutorial/BasicTutorial.html#concept_phf_cjt_ls) and am trying to debug the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the streamsets community forums: It will be the path to the *local* file on the machine *running that particular SDC instance*.

The `FileNotFound` and permission errors have to do with the fact that the default user for the sdc service is a user called `sdc`. Still working on how to fix this part, but can produce a workable prototype by setting the read and write access for the directories in question to allow public access (still need to work on this part, but this answers the posted question).